# jQuery addClass function appears to run, but doesn't actually populate the class name

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm experiencing a strange issue here.

I've developed a search box with several actions. The important bit is that it will (or it should...) open up when a user clicks the button.

HTML:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search" size="18" value="" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" value=""></input>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#searchform {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 40px;
    height: 80px;
    float: right;
}
#searchform input[type="search"] {
    margin-right: 40px;
    height:80px;
    width:2px;
    background:rgba(245, 245, 240, 1);
    padding: 0;

    -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
}
#searchform input[type="submit"] {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 80px;
}
#searchform.open input[type="search"] {
    width: 180px;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
#searchform.open input[type="submit"] {
    background:rgba(200, 160, 0, 1);
}
```

JS:

```
$('#searchform input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
    $("#searchform").toggleClass('open');
});

$('#searchform input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
    if ($('#searchform').hasClass('open') && $.trim($('#searchform input[type="search"]').val()).length === 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#searchform').removeClass('open');
    }
});

$(document).bind('click', function () {
    $('#searchform').removeClass('open');
});

$('#searchform').bind('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

And here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zB8f/1/

---

The open action is pretty simple. A jQuery script adds `class="open"` to `#searchform`, but it's only adding class ... The code seems valid, so I'm at a loss as to why it would behave like this.

If you manually add that class to the html and run it, you'll see what it's supposed to transition to.

Any help is appreciated. Bonus points if someone can tell me how to optimize that jQuery script... I'm sure I've written more than necessary for this to work...

---

Edit: I've got `toggleClass` on there now, but it behaves the same with `addClass`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need?

http://jsfiddle.net/5zB8f/3/

```
$('#searchform input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
    $("#searchform").toggleClass('open');
    if ($('#searchform').hasClass('open') && $.trim($('#searchform input[type="search"]').val()).length === 0) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if ($("#searchform").hasClass("open")) return false;
});


$(document).bind('click', function () {
    $('#searchform').removeClass('open');
});

$('#searchform').bind('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: You rock.

I injected this into my site and ran a quick test and although it's working, it threw an error... specifically: Uncaught TypeError: Object #searchform has no method 'hasClass'.

I think that's just the site though, seems fine in the fiddle.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: ah sorry, I missed a $

Comment: Can you tell me why the `event` object works in the 4th line? Where does that variable come from? I see why it works in the second to last line, where it is passed in as a parameter. But in the 4th line it isn't. Is this a jQuery shortcut I didn't know about?

Comment: I noticed that too, I don't know, I left it there as it didn't seem to break.

Comment: I needed a way to let a user click anywhere outside the box to close it so I put together that removeClass on the document click, and followed it with the function(event) and event.stopPropagation(). I had an error if I tried it with just function() and .stopPropagation. If there's a better way to do that, I'm open to it.

Edit: Also, if the search field is empty, the search button should behave as a toggle switch rather than a submit button. That should be handled by the third line there (has class-open, trim input, etc...) but it seems to redirecting anyway. I'll tinker with it though.

Comment: Ah, I see the missing $; added and error free! Thanks's Chimoo. I still need to make sure it doesn't redirect if the field is empty, but that's really minor. Thanks again :)